# Python: Create line break variable from a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, variables, line-breaks

I want to create a variable with line breaks from a list. The code below works, but doesn't seem very elegant. I'm after a better solution that I can explain to my **high school coding students**, I need follow KISS :). Any Ideas??

```
list=["frog", "owl", "cat"]

list.reverse()

word=""
for a in list:
    word=a+"\n"+word    


word=word.rstrip()
print word
```

Output

```
>>> 
frog
owl
cat
>>>
```

I had to reverse the list because I need to display item in the same order that they were entered. I used \n to dynamical add breaks but that resulted in while space so I had to strip that off.

Answer (score 3):

Use `join`.

```
>>> list=["frog", "owl", "cat"]
>>> word = "\n".join(list)
>>> print word
frog
owl
cat
```

Comment: Kevin's answer IS how you do it in Python

Comment: **Bingo!!!** very elegant and meets design brief. I **can** explain this to my coding students.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin's code was great for turn a list of strings into a line break variable

```
list=["frog", "owl", "cat"]
word = "\n".join(list)
print word
```

But it doesn't work for a list of **integers** apparently we need to use **"map"**. In this case it converts each integer to a string.

```
list_of_ints = [80, 443, 8080, 8081]
display_list=( '\n'.join(map(str, list_of_ints)))
print display_list
```

Output

```
>>> 
80
443
8080
8081
>>>
```

http://www.decalage.info/en/python/print_list, respect :)